# Not able to create or select data from Hbase table using java api

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am using the Cloudera docker , In that HBase services is up and running and able perform sorts of commands like as list and scan for particular table from Hbase shell but whenever I am trying to the same the java Api I keep getting the below error.

```
hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE
ATLAS_ENTITY_AUDIT_EVENTS
atlas_titan
employee
iemployee
test
```

a. Find the hbase-site.xml in my classpath and configuration has been loaded successfully.

```
<!--    <property>
        <name>dfs.domain.socket.path</name>
        <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/dn_socket</value>
    </property>
 -->
    <property>
        <name>hbase.bucketcache.ioengine</name>
        <value>offheap</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.bucketcache.percentage.in.combinedcache</name>
        <value></value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.bucketcache.size</name>
        <value>1024</value>
    </property>
<!-- 
    <property>
        <name>hbase.bulkload.staging.dir</name>
        <value>/apps/hbase/staging</value>
    </property> -->

    <property>
        <name>hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize</name>
        <value>1048576</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.client.retries.number</name>
        <value>35</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
        <value>100</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.coprocessor.master.classes</name>
        <value>org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor
        </value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.SecureBulkLoadEndpoint,org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor
        </value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.coprocessor.regionserver.classes</name>
        <value>org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor
        </value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.defaults.for.version.skip</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.hregion.majorcompaction</name>
        <value>604800000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.hregion.majorcompaction.jitter</name>
        <value>0.50</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.hregion.max.filesize</name>
        <value>10737418240</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.hregion.memstore.block.multiplier</name>
        <value>4</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.hregion.memstore.flush.size</name>
        <value>134217728</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.hregion.memstore.mslab.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.hstore.blockingStoreFiles</name>
        <value>10</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.hstore.compaction.max</name>
        <value>10</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.hstore.compactionThreshold</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.local.dir</name>
        <value>${hbase.tmp.dir}/local</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.master.info.bindAddress</name>
        <value>0.0.0.0</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.master.info.port</name>
        <value>16010</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.master.port</name>
        <value>16000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.master.ui.readonly</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.region.server.rpc.scheduler.factory.class</name>
        <value></value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.regionserver.global.memstore.size</name>
        <value>0.4</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.regionserver.handler.count</name>
        <value>30</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.regionserver.info.port</name>
        <value>16030</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.regionserver.port</name>
        <value>16020</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.regionserver.wal.codec</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.WALCellCodec</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/apps/hbase/data</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.rpc.controllerfactory.class</name>
        <value></value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.rpc.protection</name>
        <value>authentication</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
        <value>90000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.security.authentication</name>
        <value>simple</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.security.authorization</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.superuser</name>
        <value>hbase</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/tmp/hbase-${user.name}</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>sandbox.hortonworks.com</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.useMulti</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hfile.block.cache.size</name>
        <value>0.4</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>phoenix.functions.allowUserDefinedFunctions</name>
        <value>
        </value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>phoenix.query.timeoutMs</name>
        <value>60000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>zookeeper.recovery.retry</name>
        <value>6</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>zookeeper.session.timeout</name>
        <value>90000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
        <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
    </property>
    <!-- <property> <name>hbase.thrift.connection.max-idletime</name> <value>1800000</value> 
        </property> <property> <name>hbase.regionserver.executor.openregion.threads</name> 
        <value>100</value> </property> -->
    <property>
        <name>hbase.client.ipc.pool.type</name>
        <value>RoundRobinPool</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.client.ipc.pool.size</name>
        <value>10</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

b. Find the Java Connector for Hbase :

```
 public class HbaseConnector {
        private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HbaseConnector.class);

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
            conf.set("hbase.master", "sandbox.hortonworks.com:16010");
             conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "sandbox.hortonworks.com");
              conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
              conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");
            String TABLE_NAME = "employee1";
            try (Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf); Admin admin = connection.getAdmin()) {

                HTableDescriptor table = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_NAME));
                table.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("cf"));

                if (!admin.tableExists(table.getTableName())) {
                    System.out.print("Creating table. ");
                    admin.createTable(table);
                    System.out.println(" Done.");
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

c.Find the logs for an exception :

```
3.9.9.RELEASE-e4.12.0-win32-x86_64\sts-bundle\sts-3.9.9.RELEASE;;.
    2020-05-03 17:22:56 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\
    2020-05-03 17:22:56 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
    2020-05-03 17:22:56 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:os.name=Windows 10
    2020-05-03 17:22:56 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
    2020-05-03 17:22:56 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:os.version=10.0
    2020-05-03 17:22:56 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:user.name=username
    2020-05-03 17:22:56 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:user.home=C:\Users\username
    2020-05-03 17:22:56 INFO  ZooKeeper:100 - Client environment:user.dir=C:\Users\username\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.9.RELEASE\GDPR\HiveDataLoad
    2020-05-03 17:22:56 INFO  ZooKeeper:438 - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x7b227d8d0x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase-unsecure
    2020-05-03 17:22:57 INFO  ClientCnxn:975 - Opening socket connection to server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
    2020-05-03 17:22:59 WARN  ClientCnxn:1102 - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
    2020-05-03 17:22:59 INFO  ClientCnxn:975 - Opening socket connection to server sandbox.hortonworks.com/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
    2020-05-03 17:22:59 INFO  ClientCnxn:852 - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:59128, server: sandbox.hortonworks.com/127.0.0.1:2181
    2020-05-03 17:22:59 INFO  ClientCnxn:1235 - Session establishment complete on server sandbox.hortonworks.com/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x171d6619b910111, negotiated timeout = 40000
    2020-05-03 17:23:02 WARN  DomainSocketFactory:117 - The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because UNIX Domain sockets are not available on Windows.
    2020-05-03 17:23:58 INFO  ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation:1709 - Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x171d6619b910111
    2020-05-03 17:23:58 INFO  ZooKeeper:684 - Session: 0x171d6619b910111 closed
    2020-05-03 17:23:58 INFO  ClientCnxn:512 - EventThread shut down
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
    Sun May 03 17:23:58 IST 2020, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=61129: row 'employee1,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=sandbox.hortonworks.com,16020,1588492448730, seqNum=0

        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.throwEnrichedException(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:276)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:60)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:160)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:802)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:602)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:396)
        at HbaseConnector.main(HbaseConnector.java:79)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=61129: row 'employee1,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=sandbox.hortonworks.com,16020,1588492448730, seqNum=0
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:65)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:906)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:873)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:331)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:34094)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:203)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:360)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:334)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
        ... 4 more
```

I am happy to share my findings let's wait for yours :
Whenever i am trying to perform any DDL/DML though java api, I looked into the logs of HMaster and Region Server in dir 
/var/log/hbase and found the below error is thrown ,though Hmaster and Regions server up and running ,please correct me if I am wrong if any of them is down i won't be perform any DDL/DML using Hbase shell :

a.Regions server log: 
tail -f hbase-hbase-regionserver-sandbox.hortonworks.com.log

```
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:240)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
... 8 more
```

b.
Hmaster log: tail -f hbase-hbase-master-sandbox.hortonworks.com.log

```
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:240)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: I explore a bit more and somebody suggested to telnet on

Comment: telnet sandbox.hortonworks.com 16020, which is shown in my error log but unfortunately not able to connect, but on other port 16010 successful but in my error, it was trying to connect on 16020, after that, I tried to check the TCPView 16020 was not visible but 16010,
 VirtualBoxVM.exe 14084 TCP rashar-WX-3 16010 rashar-WX-3 0 LISTENING          
VirtualBoxVM.exe 14084 TCP rashar-WX-3 16030 rashar-WX-3 0 LISTENING          
Can someone help me get around the solution of the above problem? 
Thanks In Advance

Comment: I tried to view all the process on the docker and found this 
[root@sandbox maria_dev]#  netstat -tulpn | grep 16020
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:172.17.0.2:16020     :::*                        LISTEN      6347/java

Comment: Please update your original question instead of giving status updates in the comments. At the moment it is unclear to me what the latest status and your latest findings are.

Comment: So the latest update will remain the same, I am not able to perform any operation whether it's select or insert thought java API  and I would be happier to share latest stats 
----------->>                                                                                                                        
  
Mon May 04 13:48:15 IST 2020, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=80951: row 'iemployee,1,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=sandbox.hortonworks.com,16020,1588541244745, seqNum=0